# Create rails dynamic route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

how to create dynamic routes in rails

i need

localhost/cityA will renred cityA info

localhost/cityB about second cityB info

thats all must be on index page

params for cities will be inside dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
resources :cities, only: [ :show ], path: ''
```

and then going to `/cities/1` will show city with ID 1. If you want to have nice URLs you should take a look at [FriendlyId gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).

But foremost you should take some time to read [guide on how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)